Proving these characterizations of an 'almost open' set are equivalent
$\let\e\varepsilon \let\a\alpha$ I'm struggling to prove that all three definitions below are equivalent.
Theorem / Definition: let $\mu^*:\mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the Lebesgue outer measure. A set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ called almost open iff it complies with either of the following properties:

For any $\e>0$, there is an open $U$ containing $S$ such that $\mu^*(U\setminus S)\le \e$.
For any $\e>0$ there is some open $U$ such that $\mu^*(U\triangle S) \le \e$.
$S$ is a countable intersection $\{U_\a\}$ of open sets with a null set removed.


Context: learning new characterizations is a useful tool throughout mathematics. Thus, I tend to conjecture new definitions in my personal notes and then seek to show they are correct. If I fail to (dis)prove one of them -as in the current case- I may post it here.
In case it is needed, my background on the topic involves reading (most of?) Hunter's Measure Theory and Tao's An Introduction to Measure Theory.

Edit: fixed two mistakes in the original post.

$\mu^*$ is now the Lebesgue outer measure, as opposed to "an outer measure".
In (3) the set $S$ is a countable intersection.


It is easy to show that any subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^d$ is an intersection of some (maybe, uncountable) family of open sets.

What is the domain of $\mu^*$?

@AlexRavsky the domain of $\mu^*$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. And, yes, $S$ is the intersection of all open balls surrounding each of its points, but I still wasn't able to prove the theorem.

It would also help if some of the people who disliked the post commented on what specifically is the issue, so that I can improve the post or ask better ones moving forward (:

Something is strange in condition 3.  Is the collection ${U_\alpha}$ an arbitrary collection (possibly uncountable)? If so, then ANY set $S \subseteq \mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d}$ satisfies condition 3. In fact, for each $p \notin S$, define $U_p= \mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d} \setminus {p}$ and take $\emptyset$ as the null set. It is easy to see that  $S =(\bigcap_{p \notin S}U_p) \setminus \emptyset$.

@Sam , You wrote: "let $\mu^*:\mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an outer measure".  Do you mean an arbitrary outer measure?  Without any condition on it?

@Sam By the way, I have NOT downvoted your question.

@Sam: It is better if add more details.

@Sam , I have added a second answer to address the new version of the question. This new answer has only one upvote and my first answer is previous to the current bounty. So, if you do not assign manually the bounty before the grace period expires, the bounty will be completely lost (but not refunded to you).

@Ramiro truly sorry about that! I have set up a new bounty and will award it to your new answer in 24 hours (:

$\let\e\varepsilon \let\a\alpha$ Let us prove the following result:

Let $\mu^*:\mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the Lebesgue outer measure. Given $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$, then the four properties below are equivalent:

For any $\e>0$, there is an open $U$ containing $S$ such that $\mu^*(U\setminus S)\le \e$.
For any $\e>0$ there is some open $U$ such that $\mu^*(U\triangle S) \le \e$.
$S$ is a countable intersection $\{U_\a\}$ of open sets with a null set removed.
$S$ is Lebesgue measurable.


Proof:
$(1\implies 3)$ Assuming $1$, we have that, for each $n \in \Bbb N$ there is an open set $U_n$ containing $S$  such that $\mu^*(U_n\setminus S)\le \frac{1}{n+1}$. It follows immediately that, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $(\bigcap_n U_n)\setminus S \subseteq U_n\setminus S$. So,  for all $n \in \Bbb N$,
$ \mu^* ( (\bigcap_n U_n )\setminus S ) \le \mu^*(U_n\setminus S)\le \frac{1}{n+1}$. It follows that $ \mu^* ( (\bigcap_n U_n )\setminus S ) = 0 $. Since $S \subseteq  \bigcap_n U_n $, we have that
$S = (\bigcap_n U_n ) \setminus ( (\bigcap_n U_n )\setminus S )$. So, we have proved $3$.
$(3 \implies 4)$ It is immediate, since a countable intersection of open sets is Borel and Lebesgue measurable and any null set is Lebesgue measurable.
$(4\implies 1)$ Assume $S$ is Lebesgue measurable.
Let $\{B_m\}_{m \in \Bbb N}$ be a countable cover of $\mathbb{R}^d$ by open sets such that, for all $m \in \Bbb N$, $\mu^*(B_m) =1$. For all $m \in \Bbb N$, we have $\mu^*(S \cap B_m) \le 1$. Given any $\e >0$,
since the Lebesgue measure is outer regular and $\mu^*(S \cap B_m)$ is finite, we have that there is an open set $U_m$ such that $S \cap B_m \subseteq U_m$ and $\mu^*(U_m) < \mu^*(S \cap B_m) + \frac{\e}{2^{m+1}}$. So, since $U_m \setminus S \subseteq U_m \setminus (S \cap B_m)$ and since $U_m$, $S$ and $B_m$ are Lebesgue measurable sets, we have
$$ \mu^*(U_m \setminus S) \leqslant \mu^*(U_m \setminus (S \cap B_m) ) = \mu^*(U_m) - \mu^*(S \cap B_m)< \frac{\e}{2^{m+1}}$$
So, let $U = \bigcup_{m \in \Bbb N}U_m$. Since, for all $m$, $S \cap B_m \subseteq U_m$, we have
$  S = \bigcup_{m \in \Bbb N}(S \cap B_m) \subseteq \bigcup_{m \in \Bbb N}U_m =U $. We also have
$$ \mu^*(U \setminus S) \le  \sum_{m \in \Bbb N} \mu^*(U_m \setminus S)< \sum_{m \in \Bbb N}\frac{\e}{2^{m+1}} = \e $$
So, we proved $1$.
$(1\implies 2)$ It is immediate because, for any open set $U$ containing $S$, $U \setminus S = U \triangle S$.
$(2\implies 1)$ Assume that, for any $\e>0$,  there is some open $U$ such that $\mu^*(U\triangle S) \le \e$. So, given any $\e >0$, there is $V$ open set such that
$\mu^*(V\triangle S) \le \frac{\e}{2}$. So, by monotonicity, we have  $\mu^*(S \setminus V) \le \mu^*(V\triangle S) \le \frac{\e}{2}$. Since $\mu^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure, there is an open set $W$ such that $S \setminus V \subseteq W$ and $\mu^*(W) \le \frac{\e}{2}$.  I follows immediately that, $V \cup W$ is open, $S \subseteq V \cup W$ and $\mu^*(V \cup W) \le \mu^*(V) + \mu^*(W) \le \frac{\e}{2} + \frac{\e}{2} = \e$. Take $U=V \cup W$. We have proved $1$.
$\square$
So, $\mu^*:\mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d}\to\mathbb{R}$ being the Lebesgue outer measure, each of the properties $1$, $2$ and $3$ is equivalent to Lebesgue mesurability.

Four important remarks.

The term "almost open" is used in topology. A set $A$ is almost open if there is a an open set $U$ such that $A \triangle U$ is meager. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire

ANY set $S \subseteq \mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d}$ satisfies property $3$ as you wrote it. In fact, for each $p \notin S$, define $U_p= \mathcal{\mathbb{R}^d} \setminus \{p\}$ and take $\emptyset$ as the null set. It is easy to see that  $S =(\bigcap_{p \notin S}U_p) \setminus \emptyset$.

If $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary outer measure,  without any additional condition on it. Then the only true implication is $(1\implies 2)$, which is easy to prove since, for any open set $U$ containing $S$, $U \setminus S = U \triangle S$. On the other hand, in the general case of an arbitrary outer measure, $(2\implies 1)$ is false. Here is a counter-example:



Let $E = \left \{\frac{1}{n+1} : n \in \Bbb N \right \}$. Let $d=1$ and $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ be the outer measure defined by, for any $B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mu^*(B) = \#(B \cap E)$ , where $\#$ is the number of elements of a finite set and it is $+\infty$ if the set is infinite.
Let $S=[-1,0]$. Then taking $U = (-1,0)$, we have $U \triangle S = \{-1,0\}$ and so $\mu^*(U \triangle S) = \mu^*(\{-1,0\})=0$. So $S$ clearly satisfies property $2$.
However, for any open set $U$ containing $S$, we have $0\in U$ so $U$ has infinitely many elements of $E$ and, since $S$ and $E$ are disjoint, $U \setminus S$ also  has infinitely many elements of $E$. So, for any open set $U$ containing $S$, $\mu^*(U \setminus S) = \infty$. So, $S$ does NOT satisfy property $1$.


Even if you change property $3$ to refer to countable intersection of open sets, it will not be true that $(3\implies 1)$. Note that, in the counter-example presented above, $S = [-1,0]$ is the countable intersection of open sets, so it satisfies property $3$, but not property $1$.

